# What is the purpose of the database files owner?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014, I restore a database and when I go to Database Properties\Files I see this window. By default it put my user after restore it but I changed to sa. What's the importance of setting this user and which one should be the default one or the correct one?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to move this to dba stack exchange.

Comment: I tried but I have this "You can only post once every 40 minutes." and I didn't post anything

Comment: This link provides the best a good explanation.  Clear and concise.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905163(v=sql.80).aspx